# Buttons run together in Bootstrap 2.0.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.0.1, and in my pages I often have a couple of buttons next to each other:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large x-create-quiz">Create Quiz</a>
<a class="btn x-cancel">Cancel</a></div>
```

The buttons render next to each other, with no spacing between them.

I've had to add a `&nbsp;` between the two.

Looking at the source of the Twitter Bootstrap documention, they do the same thing, but get a small space between the buttons.

Any idea why?  I'd prefer to eliminate the  .  Could there be some enclosing `<div>` somewhere that provides the gap?

I've gotten the same results in Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: Also, doesn't make a difference between `<a>` and `<button>` for the tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. I'm using node/express/jade and found that jade will remove any whitespace on delivery by default, resulting in something like this:

```
<button class="...">reset</button><button class="...">save</button>
```

Your buttons won't run together if there is whitespace between them. For jade you may
explicitly add space via `= ' '` between your buttons or choose to enable pretty printing:

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true })
```

Hope this is of help to you, took me some time to realize this behavior...

Comment: That seems to fit my scenario perfectly, and even with FireBug, it's a challenge to identify page structure including whitespace.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with Jade, and your comment solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: As Twilight Pony Inc. points out: since express 4 things changed, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

The gap comes about from the white-space that the font-size makes on their container, in this case the `p` tag, and if no font-size is available the `body` tag. You can remove that white-space by setting the font-size to 0 on the `p` and `body` tag (or container, if any is available) and you can increase the white-space of course by setting a higher font-size.

So, i would suggest you make sure that you have a proper font-size declared on your `body` tag, on the element itself, or in the container of your element.

You can test this on the twitters bootstrap documentation page by adding an inline style with firebug in FF or the inspector tool in Chrome to the `p` tag of a button group so you can see how they stick together.

```
<p style="font-size:0">...</p>
```

Comment: Just verified behavior is the same on Boostrap 2.0.2.

Comment: I can see on the Bootstrap demo pages that setting the font-size of the containing `<p>` to 0 creates the same effect.  However, looking at my page, I can see that the containing `<div class='well'`> inherits `font-size: 13px` from the `<body>` element (bootstrap.css:133) ... so I still don't understand why it looks different on my page (buttons run together with no gap) than (as I understand it) identical content on the bootstrap demo page. Weird.

Comment: @HowardM.LewisShip Can you replicate your issue with jsFiddle? I created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVj8B/) with some buttons with the proper font-size in place (from the bootstrap) inside a `.well` div and its working fine by default.

Comment: I think this was because I was using Jade template engine, which is nicely stingy about the amount of whitespace it injects.  Adding an explicit space (not a &nbsp;) fixed the problem.

In addition, using a .btn-toolbar and .btn-group fixed it without additional explicit whitespace.

Comment: @HowardM.LewisShip yeah, maybe it was removing that space after the buttons, if you remove the whitespace between the buttons and place them side by side in your markup they will run together.